# SQL Query returns no results when using declared variables, but does when plugging in those values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL which grabs the value of the 'floor' and 'unit' from a table, and attempts to match those values with records in another table.

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)
DECLARE @lockerUnit varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerUnitNumber  FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)

SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor] = @lockerFloor AND unit = @lockerUnit
```

The above returns no results. However, if I do the following:

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)
DECLARE @lockerUnit varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerUnitNumber  FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)

SELECT @lockerFloor AS 'Floor', @lockerUnit AS 'Unit'
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Now, if I run this query using the results above, I do get the expected result

```
SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor]='LKR' AND unit='241'
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to build a cut-down reproducible example using a temp table to allow us to experience the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you *really* need 2 GB of storage for the value of `lockerFloorArea` and `lockerUnitNumber` (something defined as a **number**)?

Comment: If `lockerUnitNumber` ***is** a number*, you're inferring that you might need to store the number `1E+2147483648-1`. That is a HUGE number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:Facepalm:

The data in the t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers table was populated via a BULK INSERT from a CSV file. It was importing the lockerUnitNumber value with a linebreak. Replacing the line break on select fixed the issue

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(100) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers ORDER BY idx desc)
DECLARE @lockerUnit varchar(100) = (SELECT TOP(1) REPLACE(REPLACE(lockerUnitNum,CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')  FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers ORDER BY idx desc)
SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor] = @lockerFloor AND unit = @lockerUnit
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is very simple:

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea 
                                     FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)
```

Top without explicit `ORDER BY` is undeterministic.  `@lockerFloor` could have different value between multiple executions.

[No Seatbelt – Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

---

Running:

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)
DECLARE @lockerUnit varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerUnitNumber  FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)

SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor] = @lockerFloor AND unit = @lockerUnit
```

It could return any arbitary pair. We could reproduce it by using helper variables.

```
DECLARE @lockerFloor varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerFloorArea FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)
DECLARE @lockerUnit varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) lockerUnitNumber  FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers)

DECLARE @helper_lockerFloor VARCHAR(MAX) = @lockerFloor,
        @helper_lockerUnit  VARCHAR(MAX) = @lockerUnit;

SELECT @helper_lockerFloor,@helper_lockerUnit;

SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units 
WHERE [floor] = @helper_lockerFloor AND unit = @helper_lockerUnit;
```

Comment: even adding ORDER BY idx DESC OR WHERE idx=X to each of those still returns no results.

Comment: @DigitalFusion Did you run code with helper variables? Is `idx` column unique?

Comment: idx is unique, there is only one row of data in the table, and the helper vars produce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

1. Your table has some indexes
2. The actual query plan of the first query is performing each `select top(1)` using different indexes
3. The second query you ran is a different TSQL batch that was optimized differently

You can prove this by looking at the actual query plan to see what it did.  You can obtain an actual plan by the SSMS option "Include Actual Execution Plan (CTRL+M)", or by using an extended event session, or by using the deprecated SQL Profiler.

Even if there are no other indexes, your first queries are free to select whatever `top` row they want, because there is no `order by` specified, and they are separate queries.

In your first query, try setting both variables at once on the same `top` row:

```
-- use the same type as the column type to avoid implicit conversions
DECLARE
    @lockerFloor varchar(100), -- changed from varchar(max)
    @lockerUnit varchar(100) -- changed from varchar(max)

SELECT TOP 1
    @lockerFloor = [lockerFloorArea],
    @lockerUnit = [lockerUnitNumber]
FROM t_users_tempImport_parkingLockers

SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor] = @lockerFloor AND unit = @lockerUnit
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT id FROM t_buildings_units WHERE [floor] = '' + @lockerFloor + '' AND unit = '' + @lockerUnit + ''
```

Comment: Why `'' + @lockerFloor + '' `? what does the `''` on either side achieve?

Comment: The variables are string values.

Comment: *"The variables are string values."* So why wrap it in empty strings?

Comment: @Larnu: SQL 2014,2016 don't even bother having the single quotes. Now, I suspect that older versions of SQL (2005,2008) may require a quote wrapper just like that. Having two single quotes around works. If three quotes are used, then it needs to be executed as a dynamic sql.

Comment: I doubt that was even syntax needed back in SQL Server 2000. Certainly it wasn't 2005. Why would you, however, use syntax was was required by SQL Server 7.0? That's been unsupported for over a decade.